# I want to display some information with value while inputting user

Tags: python, input

I want to display some information while getting user input, for example I would like to do something like:

```
for i in range(5): 
    bug=int(input('Enter the number of bugs collected for day ',i+1))
```

And get something like

```
Enter the number of bugs collected for day 1
Enter the number of bugs collected for day 2 
...
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `range` has an optional argument to specify the start of the range. Using this with `f` strings:

```
for i in range (1, 6): 
    bug = int(input(f'Enter the number of bugs collected for day {i}: '))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate the value of (i+1) after converting it to a String. Do the following:

```
for i in range (5):
    bug=int(input('Enter the number of bugs collected for day '+str(i+1)+': '))
```